# Generalized Inverse Gaussian Distribution, implementation to data set

Tags: distribution

I have a data set with one variable & total of 300 observations. I am trying to implement The Generalized Hyperbolic Distribution in r. Are there any examples out there for me to look at it & understand the steps in The Generalized Hyperbolic Distribution. 
Thanks for any lead.

Comment: How about https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/GeneralizedHyperbolic/GeneralizedHyperbolic.pdf ?

Comment: Please note item #4 in the [site help docs for what's on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).